# twitter bootstraps, youtube api, dynamic slider in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, youtube-api, slider

I'm trying to make **YouTube Video carousel Slider with YouTube API** with reference to **CodePen Stuff**,
I don't know how to make this slider **Dynamically** in PHP I'm just beginner In PHP
It is **possible** to to add just **YouTube Video ID** Through Back-end then it will appear to Front-end as a Slider.

**my codepen link is here** : https://codepen.io/guenon/pen/ExKGQez

```js
//Start Youtube API
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

var youtubeReady = false;

//Variable for the dynamically created youtube players
var players= new Array();
var isPlaying = false;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){
  //The id of the iframe and is the same as the videoId 
  jQuery(".youtube-video").each(function(i, obj)  {
     players[obj.id] = new YT.Player(obj.id, {         
              videoId: obj.id,
                playerVars: {
                controls: 2,
              rel:0,
              autohide:1,
              showinfo: 0 ,
              modestbranding: 1,
              wmode: "transparent",
              html5: 1
        },    
        events: {
          'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        }
       });
     });
     youtubeReady = true;
  }


function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  var target_control =  jQuery(event.target.getIframe()).parent().parent().parent().find(".controls");
  
  var target_caption = jQuery(event.target.getIframe()).parent().find(".carousel-caption");
  switch(event.data){
    case -1:
      jQuery(target_control).fadeIn(500);
      jQuery(target_control).children().unbind('click');
      break
     case 0:
      jQuery(target_control).fadeIn(500);
      jQuery(target_control).children().unbind('click');
      break;
     case 1:
      jQuery(target_control).children().click(function () {return false;});
      jQuery(target_caption).fadeOut(500);
      jQuery(target_control).fadeOut(500);
       break;
      case 2:
        jQuery(target_control).fadeIn(500);
        jQuery(target_control).children().unbind('click'); 
        break;
        case 3:
           jQuery(target_control).children().click(function () {return false;});
           jQuery(target_caption).fadeOut(500);
           jQuery(target_control).fadeOut(500);
           break;
          case 5:
            jQuery(target_control).children().click(function () {return false;});
            jQuery(target_caption).fadeOut(500);
            jQuery(target_control).fadeOut(500);
            break;
          default:
            break;
    }
};

jQuery(window).bind('load', function(){
  jQuery(".carousel-caption").fadeIn(500);
  jQuery(".controls").fadeIn(500);
 });

jQuery('.carousel').bind('slid.bs.carousel', function (event) {
   jQuery(".controls").fadeIn(500);
});
```

```css
.video-container { 
   position: relative; /* keeps the aspect ratio */ 
   padding-bottom: 45%; /* fine tunes the video positioning */ 
   padding-top: 60px; overflow: hidden;
   margin-bottom: -1px;
   margin-right: -1px;   
}

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed {
  position: absolute;  
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
  
.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left{
  top:35%;
  font-size: 20px;
  left:50%;
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right{
  top:35%;
  font-size: 20px;
  left:33%;
  margin: 0;
}

.carousel-control.left, .carousel-control.right {
  background-image: none;
  color: red;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
  opacity: 1;
  height:120px;
}

.controls{
   display: none;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  filter: alpha(opacity=60);
  outline: 0;
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.left-button {
  height:70px;
  width:35px;
  border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
  -moz-border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
/*   background-color: #e25454; */
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  /*subpixel bug*/
  margin-left: -1px; 
}

.right-button {
  height:70px;
  width:35px;
  border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0,-50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(0,-50%);
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
  -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
/*   background-color: #e25454; */
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float:right;
  /*subpixel bug*/
  margin-right: -1px;
}


.carousel-caption {
 display: none;
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #e25454;
  bottom: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 1;
  padding:7px 30px 7px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  z-index:11;
  pointer-events:none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.right-button {
  height:120px;
  width:60px;
  border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
  -moz-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 90px 0 0 90px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float:right;
}

.left-button {
  height:120px;
  width:60px;
  border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 90px 90px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  float:left;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-left{
  top:35%;
  font-size: 35px;
  left:5%;
}

.carousel-control .glyphicon-chevron-right{
  top:35%;
  font-size: 35px;
  left:35%;
}

.carousel-caption {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding:15px 20px 15px;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
 .carousel-caption {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding:15px 20px 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
      <h1 style="color: black">Testing</h1>
      <p style="color: black">Replace the IDs of the carousel items with the IDs of the youtube videos you want to display</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
      <div id="random_number1" class="carousel slide youtube-carousel"  data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="video-container item active">
            <div class="youtube-video" id='vjn-Gh-4wxU'></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">Video 1</div>
          </div>
          <div class="video-container item">
            <div class="youtube-video" id='6MjRVkm9CF0'></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">Video 2</div>
          </div>
          <div class="video-container item ">
            <div class="youtube-video" id='R8poo-zCK9g'></div>
            <div class="carousel-caption">Video 3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#random_number1" data-slide="prev">
            <div class="left-button">
              <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#random_number1" data-slide="next">        
            <div class="right-button">
              <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How is this a php related question?

Comment: I want to make this as a dynamically